# Assigning externally loaded image to movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have existing "replay_btn" movie clip. Initially, on stage it is blank. In as3 code, I'm loading an external image using xml.
Like this,

```
 var replaySlideImage:Loader = new Loader();
  replaySlideImage.y = 561;
  replaySlideImage.load(new URLRequest(xmlPath.replayButton.icon));
  addChild(replaySlideImage);
```

Now, when I run the swf file, the loaded image goes on top of the replay_btn move clip. I want to know,
how do I make the "replay_btn" tell that the loaded image is your background image.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Do you need to replace the background of the replay_btn movieclip with the loaded image?

Comment: Yes, I want to load external image as background of the replay_btn movieclip.

Comment: simply do `replay_btn.addChild(replaySlideImage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addChildAt()` rather than `addChild()` to assign a DisplayObject's index when adding it to the stage.

```
addChildAt(replaySlideImage, 0);
```